# Downloading a script file using selenium giving, This type of file can harm your computer popup

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

While downloading a python script file using selenium webdriver getting  a popup which saying "This type of file can harm your computer..." then keep and discard button. i do not want that popup . while clicking on download it should download without the popup. i am running the script in Chrome 75 version.

And tried putting

```
chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "false");
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist");
options.addArguments("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection");
```

this while initializing the driver , but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Boilerplate code for setting driver and download path
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "--driver path--");
String path = "Download path";
HashMap<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//setting browser preference values such as popup and download path 
chromePrefs.put("profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups", 2);
chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "true");
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", path);

//Boilerplate code for setting preferences in chrome options
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Above code snippet should help you to create a chrome driver, with popups disabled capability.

for this to work on different versions of chrome you might have to play around with 
    "managed_default_content_settings.popups" or 
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups"
attributes and its values (0,1 or 2).

Hope this helps !!

Comment: "Try this" with a bunch of code afterwards is not very helpful. You've added a lot of code but haven't explained why any of it was added or what it's supposed to do. Adding some description of the lines you added and why would potentially make this a good answer.

Comment: thanks for your feedback @JeffC, will add more description to it.

Comment: @Vishal Kumar even i tried all the combination ,nothing worked for me